# Windows Information Protection Doesn't work on my system

Tags: windows, security

I have a WIP profile installed in some windows 10 systems, when r-click a file and change the file owner to the group, such as company.com. Normally, once I change the owner to group(domain), the file can not be moved to a network shared folder and prompt "permission is required". But I have one system has no such restriction, i.e., file still can be copied or moved to share folder w/o freely. May I know what makes the difference? Will joining or not joining in  a domain impact the result?

Comment: From the failed system to access a network shared folder, I found all the files' "file ownership" in shared folder as shown as "company.com", so when I copy a local file(file owership has been set to company.com) to the shared folder, since it think the file ownership will not be change to personal, so it can be copied. So the question is, why the files in shared folder are shown file ownership as company.com?

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. The IP range is the root cause. The share folder should not within the IP range of IP isolation, set by WIP.